# Password restrictions to support international travellers

Tags: keyboard, passwords, letters, chars

Yes, using any restrictions on the letters that a user can put in his password weakens security. But on the other hand: have you ever tried the Euro sign (€) on a Thai keyboard? Or a German Umlaut (Ä) on an English keyboard?

For this reason I have been using the following regex restriction for my travelling customers for years now:

`^[0-9a-zA-Z @.\-_+]+$` (so basically numbers, letters, blank and @ . - _ + are allowed).

Although there have never been complaints (and more importantly people were able to login no matter which keyboard layout) I want to extend this collection of letters.

Which letters are safe to use - no matter what kind of national keyboard a user has?

Comment: Btw. on my research I tried TripAdvisors password policy: they actually allow something like `@€~µพ123` (having a Thai letter in the middle) which will work almost nowhere without any tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

I would go ahead and say all letters are safe. If they can type it on their home computer I don't see why restricting them to a national patterned keyboard would be a problem.

However, I would be more concerned with what can be typed on a cellphone keyboard. Holding down the keys generally gives you a lot of options to include international symbols.

Mobile devices are much more common than personal computers and this gap is only growing.

Comment: Does this help? Personal computing is becoming legacy the as technology expands. Unless you are writing a program for a business I would focus on mobile capabilities for passwords.

Comment: Well, it does help insofar as you reminded me that I'm far behind with my project, that has been running 15 years now. But it doesn't solve my problem as I am currently transfering to a new Symfony based backend - while the "mobile unfriendly" frontend stays the same for at least the next 6 months.